# Aligning stacked function plot and another tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a function plotted pgfplots, but I need to stack or overlay a bar **below** and parallel to x-axis, from origin the first zero of the function. The problem I have is that I can't explicitly set the axis length (not the plot width) of pgfplot. The relevant code I have is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
% 1.28 is the approximate zero of the black function
\draw[very thick] (0, -1) -- (\textwidth*0.4/1.5*1.28, -1); 
\begin{axis}[
    ticks=none,
    domain=0:1.5,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1.5,
    ymin=0,
    x=\textwidth*0.4/1.5, % I thought this would make it work
    axis lines=left,
    xlabel={$r$ \color{red}$r^2$},
    ylabel=$m$,
    y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.15, 0.5)}, anchor=south},
    x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5, 0.1)}},
    axis equal,
]
\addplot[mark=none, thick] (x, {1 - x^2 + x/2});
\addplot[mark=none, color=red] (x^2, {1 - x^2 + x/2});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and the result I got was (ignore the circle please)

[image]

it's obvious that the two doesn't really have the same length. In fact, if shifted, the result was (*This is not the desired diagram, just to show how the two don't align*)

[image]

In simple words, the effect I want is to have the black bar touch with the black function exactly on that point. I would also like to know if there's any way to not hard code the solution of the function and let tikz determine it.

Comment: Using the `intersections` Ti*k*z library is the way to go to automatically determine the intersections of the lines. To just draw it because you know the points to connect, you can use `\draw[very thick] (axis cs: 0,0) -- (axis cs: 1.28, 0);` **inside** the `axis` environment and, as you can see, you can refer to the cartesian plane using the axis coordinate system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way: compute the intersection with the x-axis and draw the line then. **UPDATE**: Accommodated the revised question (I think).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ticks=none,
    domain=0:1.5,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1.5,
    ymin=0,
    axis lines=left,
    xlabel={$r$ \color{red}$r^2$},
    ylabel=$m$,
    y label style={at={(axis description cs:0, 0.5)}, anchor=south},
    x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5, 0.1)}},
    axis equal,
]
\addplot[mark=none, thick,name path=B] (x, {1 - x^2 + x/2});
\addplot[mark=none, thick,draw=none,name path=A] (x, 0);
\addplot[mark=none, color=red] (x^2, {1 - x^2 + x/2});
\path [name intersections={of=A and B,by={X}}];
\coordinate (O) at (0,-0.1);
\end{axis}
\draw[very thick,blue] (O-|X) circle (1pt); 
\draw[very thick,blue] (O) circle (1pt); 
\draw[very thick,blue] (O) -- (O-|X) coordinate[midway] (Y); 
\draw[blue] ($(Y)+(0,2pt)$) -- ($(Y)-(0,2pt)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I vote +1 for your answer. I have not understood the question of the OP.

Comment: @Sebastiano Grazie! I am also not 100% sure but I was under the impression that "In simple words, the effect I want is to have the black bar touch with the black function exactly on that point. " means (s)he wants to draw the line all the way to the intersection of the black curve with the x-axis.

Comment: @marmot I also understood it in this way and you were quicker than me! ;) I do not understand why the label in your plot are inside the plot, though. Completing and compiling the code of the OP, the labels are as shown in his/her picture.

Comment: @AxelKrypton I was also wondering about this, but how can you compile the code of the OP? You need to add `\documentclass` and so on, and that's what I did. Anyway, I added an alternative.

Comment: @marmot As I said, *completing* and compiling the OP's code. I just added `\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}` and `\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}` (together with the `document` environment). I was wondering about the position of your label not because they look bad (even if they do), but because your code is almost identical to the OP one. At least, the `x` and `y label style`s are identical (those of your first code). And, then, I do not understand who is the responsible of the shift. Any clue?

Comment: @AxelKrypton Yes, it is `y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.15, 0.5)}, anchor=south},`. Once I modified it, it looks good. BTW, what are you using for `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}`?

Comment: Thanks, but sorry for the ambiguity. I indeed meant what you and @AxelKrypton understood it as, but I need the bar, in the final solution to be below the axis, parallel to it. That way I believe I couldn't use the `intersection`. I'll make another revision to my question to show the desired output in a moment.

Comment: @YiFei It is straightforward to accomplish this, please see my update.

Comment: @YiFei ... and of course the circles are just for illustration, you can remove them by deleting `\draw[very thick,blue] (O-|X) circle (1pt); 
\draw[very thick,blue] (O) circle (1pt); `.

Comment: Thanks! But I have yet another question... is it possible to mark the midpoint of that blue line?

Comment: @YiFei Yes, there are plenty of options. I added one of them to my answer (assuming that you want to use the midpoint somehow). Other options include `decorations.markings`.

Comment: @marmot Yes, you are right, I was not specifying the `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}`, it was too late... ;) In any case, do you know why, *not* specifying it and then letting it running in backward compatibility mode (as the compiler warns) affects the position of the labels? I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

this is rather extended comment than answer... so please don't vote it.

code in [emarmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot) answer can be shorter:

- by considering `pgfplots 1.15`
- by move common `addplot` options to `axis` options
- by considering that default position of `y label` is the same as it is defined by `y label style`

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ticks=none,
    domain=0:1.5,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1.5,
    ymin=0,
    axis lines=left,
    xlabel={$r$ \color{red}$r^2$},
    ylabel=$m$,
    x label style={at={(0.5, 0.1)}},
    axis equal,
    mark=none,
    every axis plot post/.append style={very thick}
]
\addplot[name path=B] {1 - x^2 + x/2};
\addplot[draw=none,name path=A] (x,0);
\addplot[color=red] (x^2, {1 - x^2 + x/2});
\path [name intersections={of=A and B,by={X}}];
\end{axis}
\filldraw[very thick,blue] (0,-0.25) circle (1pt) -- (X |- 0,-0.25) circle (1pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have upvoted same :-( +1

Comment: I believe that those who dedicate their precious time to provide an adequate and comprehensive response must be rewarded.